# ZeroMQ multiple topics in publisher

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

List **`a`** and **`b`** are the keys and the values. The values in variable `b` are assigned as topicnumbers and data is sent every 10 seconds to a topic. Is this is a stable way to distribute information? Does one see any difficulties for in the near future when the keys and thus topics are scaled up to 100+?

```
import zmq
import random
import time
from  multiprocessing import Process

a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
b = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
d = dict(zip(a, b))

def pub001():
    port = "5100"    
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)

    while True:
        for i, x in d.items():
            topic = x
            number = random.randrange(1, 215)
            print(topic, number)
            socket.send_string("%d %d" % (topic, number))
            print("Data published", topic)
            time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a =Process(target=pub001, args=())
    a.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

### Scaling-wise?

No. If you read details about the `<_Topic-filter_>`-processing, there is space ~ 4 orders of magnitude ( 10.000 x larger trees yet work ), so need not expect a problem from static counts in the range of a few hundreds ( if you correctly scale the node's storage-resources, as per which side is actually doing the `<_Topic-filter_>` processing ).

---

### Performance-wise?

Sure, if machines talk each to any other, design a better information representation, than to wrap it into an extremely redundant string of human-readable, but extremely inefficient ( and expensive on both { local + transport + remote }-{ processing + storage } ), data-representation.

For utmost latency-envelopes, a way smarter, bitmapped ( and possibly TimeDOMAIN coalesced ) payloads make a way better sense.